# Flutter iOS Firebase Analytics ans Crashlytics not showing up

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, crashlytics, firebase-analytics

I have a running Android and iOS version of my flutter app. I followed the integration steps for firebase as instructed and also added the google-service.json trough xcode. The database connection runs without problems, same with Auth.
In my firebase console the iOS usage statistics are always zero and also the crashlytics does not show up correctly. Any additional steps I need to follow to resolve those?

Timo

Comment: As you said you added google-service.json file through Xcode. In Xcode you have to put up GoogleServicesInfo.plist file and not the json one

Comment: Pay attention that Firebase Analytics is not delivered to Firebase servers right away. On smartphones for battery savings the data is batch uploaded at certains intervals - for Android e.g. there is a Debug mode for Analytics enabled in DevTools that allows to skip this time lags and show diagnostic UI in Firebase. In Web when using Google Analytics you can typically see the actions on the web site reflected in GA Console almost instantly.

Comment: Not sure if this is how you tried this, but when testing in iOS you will need to run the app, then stop Xcode after the app gets installed in the device, then you will need to open the app directly in the device and crash it. The debugger from Xcode prevents Crashlytics from collecting crashes.

Answer (score 0):

On my end the Analytics works but not the Crashlytics, it stays on pending add SDK, no idea why. I've been able to trigger a dummy crash but it hasn't been reported after restarting the app.